# How to register nested routes on an Angular standalone component?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-standalone-components

I need to migrate the component/view below (with nested routes) from NgModule to standalone

[Angular docs for routing](https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview) do not mention standalone, and [standalone docs](https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview) only show how to route *to* a standalone component

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-account",
  templateUrl: "./account.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./account.component.scss"],
})
export class AccountComponent {}

export const AccountRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: AccountComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "register",
        component: RegisterComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "confirm",
        component: ConfirmComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(AccountRoutes)],
  declarations: [AccountComponent, LoginComponent, RegisterComponent, ConfirmComponent],
})
export class AccountModule {}
```

I tried `provideRouter` like below, but it seems it can only be used with `bootstrapApplication`, with the error: `Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes)
  ],
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss'],
})
export class AccountComponent {}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you're probably trying to achieve is this;

```
// In the main application:
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [
  {path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/routes').then(mod => mod.ADMIN_ROUTES)},
  // ...
];

// In admin/routes.ts:
export const ADMIN_ROUTES: Route[] = [
  {path: 'home', component: AdminHomeComponent},
  {path: 'users', component: AdminUsersComponent},
  // ...
];
```

This piece of information is hidden in here: [lazy loading many routes at once](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#lazy-loading-many-routes-at-once)

In essense, this acts identical to the `loadChildren()` function of an angular submodule that you'd lazily load. But in my understanding, that is all you can do. You will not be able to have a nested router providers in your standalone components. You are only allowed to do this at AppComponent bootstrapping.

This is probably why they say,

> an NgModule is no longer required in many **common**, lazy-loading scenarios. [1](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#lazy-loading-many-routes-at-once)

If you must do deeply nested lazy loading (like in massive apps with large dev groups), I would still go with an ngModule inside a standalone app, that will completely isolate its business logic from the main app.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48950

Comment: Thank you for the thorough comment, this might work indeed.  
But in the example provided, the route `"admin"` doesn't have a `component` entry, therefore can't have a template to wrap children with `<router-outlet>` which is a requirement for me

Comment: Could you may be create a placeholder component place a router outlet in that and then define children routes. 

I usually set a route path `’’` and put a component with an outlet. Then add child routes with the desired paths. 

Would that be an option?

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your sample code, simply swap out all instances of **component** with **loadComponent** and the instance of **children** with **loadChildren** after converting all the referenced components to be standalone.

**loadChildren** will necessitate your nested routes array living in a separate file, e.g. nested.routes.ts, in order to fulfill its arrow function + import syntax.

We're currently on Angular 16.2.1 and found empirically that this works as nested router-outlets should.